# Python RotatingFileHandler not rotating

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to limit the size of log file in Python, using RotatingFileHandler.

I am using the following code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(logging.basicConfig(
    filename = log_filename,
    handlers = [logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=log_filename, maxBytes=1024, backupCount=20)],
    format = "%(asctime)s %(message)s",
    level = logging.DEBUG))
```

I visited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401571/python-3-logger-with-rotatingfilehandler-excedes-maxbytes-limit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095578/why-does-python-rotatingfilehandlers-maxbytes-not-work/48095853). I am using both maxBytes and backupCount parameters, but it is still not working.
Any idea why the log file is not rotating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7 does not support the `handlers` argument in [logging.basicConfig()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) function.
So you have to move the handler out of the basicConfig arguments, like that:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=log_filename, maxBytes=1024, backupCount=20)
handler.setFormatter("%(asctime)s %(message)s")
logger.addHandler(handler)
```